# How to reach previous position on same page in java-script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a long `HTML page`, and on page I have given some `links` to open an `overlay` to show some data, and when I collapse the `overlay` I reach `top` of the page while if I clicked to open `overlay` at end of the page it should be reach at that position.

I did `Google` but didn't get any proper solution.

Here is my `jQuery` code

This code is use to open `overlay`

```
 $(document.body).on('click', '.viewAllArt', function () {       
        $('.articleAll').css('display', 'none');
        $('.viewMain').css('display', 'none');

        $('.articleAll').css('display', 'block');
    });
```

This code use to close `overlay`

```
   $('.collapsColony').click(function () {
        $('.articleAll').css('display', 'none');
        $('.articleAll').css('display', 'none');
        $('.viewMain').css('display', 'block');
    });
```

Sorry I don't have any `plunker` link to show, since most of the file is dependent to each other.

Any suggestion will be helpful for me.

**UPDATED**

Comment: Please post your code if you want someone to help you, or make a jfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your position when opening the overlay. Then, scroll to the stored position when you close the overlay.

You can use jQuery's [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) function for this.

Edit: Code Example

```js
var position;

$("button").click(function(){
  if(!!position)
     $(document).scrollTop(position);
});
$("p").click(function(){
  position = $(document).scrollTop();
});




$(document.body).on('click', '.viewAllArt', function() {
  $('.articleAll').css('display', 'none');
  $('.viewMain').css('display', 'none');

  $('.articleAll').css('display', 'block');
  position = $(document).scrollTop();
});

$('.collapsColony').click(function() {
  $('.articleAll').css('display', 'none');
  $('.articleAll').css('display', 'none');
  $('.viewMain').css('display', 'block');
  $(document).scrollTop(position);
});
```

```css
button{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p><p><a href="#">Lorem</a></p></div>
<button>SCROLL</button>
```

Edit : I updated the example to show that it is indeed working. Your problem is probably somewhere else in your code.

Comment: It's not working in my code, getting same issue, every time I am getting `0 value`

Comment: Thanks, for your respond @Ozan I'll figure out my problm

Comment: You are welcome. If you post more of your code related to the context I could try and see why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

On opening the overlay save your screen scroll position using

```
var positionvalue= $(document).scrollTop()

    //you can save positionvalue in a cookie
```

in local storage. Later when you return to your page, use this value to restore your screen position

```
//retrieve positionvalue from the previously saved cookie
    $(document).scrollTop(positionvalue);
```

Comment: I didn't understand your last line, can you please explain it, and how to get my `positionvalue`